# Google OAuth2 API missing setServiceAccountUser method in .Net

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to impersonate user using the Google OAuth library as given in the following Google API documentation.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

It has given sample code in java but not in .net.
According to that java sample code( I am coping the code snippet from that documentation), it has the method setServiceAccountUser()

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(emailAddress).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12")).setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton    (SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN)).setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com").build();
```

But when I tried to use the google package Google.Apis.Auth in C#, it has the GoogleCredential class but the method is not available in that class.

Is there any way to set ServiceAccountId like in java sample code?

Any suggestion or comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution as given in the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496919/googlecredential-created-by-json-private-key-file-serviceaccount-how-to-set

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim stream As FileStream = New FileStream("path/to/credentials.json")
credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser("user@impersonate.com")
```